# WebView with an image doesnt stay in center after zoom(double tap)

Tags: android, webview

I have been trying to show a image in WebView. The image could be large and could be of dimensions bigger than device. I chose to use `Webview` as it is capable of showing large images.

However, it is difficult to show a `WebView` with image inside a layout and keep it around center. With the following code the image shows up fine in center in the beginning but as soon as I start double tapping it zooms in and zooms out and moves all over the screen. It finally settles aligned to the top of the device scree and just wont wont move from there.

I am missing something here. Are there any specific ways to achieve a center aligned image in a `WebView`?

What I am looking for is:

- Webview should expand and collapse as double tap toggles
- Image should zoom in and zoom out but zoom should respect the image position in center. It should come back in original position when zoomed out.

Any help is much appreciated thanks

Here is my layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight = "10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"

            />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the activity source code:

```
public class TestActivity7 extends Activity {

    String largeURL = "http://test.png";
    WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        //   webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(25);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.loadUrl(largeURL);



    }
}
```